# How to set woocommerce product image as background image in shop page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to replace src="image_url" to style="background: url('image_url')" of product image in shop page.
How should i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are more comfortable, you have 2 possible ways:

1. in your theme create a folder structure of `woocommerce\single-product\`, copy inside it the file you can find at `\wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\templates\single-product\product-image.php` and edit the HTML;
2. in your theme `functions.php` add a filter on the `woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html` hook and replace the HTML passed by (maybe using some regex)

Comment: Thank you but i don't want to change anything in single product page I want to change in shop page. How can i change that?